# Error en Observer al ejecutar con Tkinter Python - NameError: name 'observer' is not defined,

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter

Estoy intentando crear una APP que monitore una carpeta, Me aler si se elimina,modifica, crear algun archivo.
Tengo problemas al implementar **Watchdog** con **Tkinter** pero con POO, estuve investigando por todos lados pero ninguno funciona.
Esto son las librerias

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import datetime
import queue
import tkinter as tk


from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import (
    EVENT_TYPE_CREATED,
    EVENT_TYPE_DELETED,
    EVENT_TYPE_MODIFIED,
    EVENT_TYPE_MOVED
)
```

La Clase `***CarpPrincial(FileSystemEventHandler)***`

```
class CarpPrincial(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, q):
        self._q = q
        super().__init__()
    
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        action = {
            EVENT_TYPE_CREATED: "Creado",
            EVENT_TYPE_DELETED: "Eliminado",
            EVENT_TYPE_MODIFIED: "Modificado",
            EVENT_TYPE_MOVED: "Movido",
        }[event.event_type]
        if event.event_type == EVENT_TYPE_MOVED:
            action += f" ({event.dest_path})"

        self._q.put((
            # Nombre del archivo modificado.
            Path(event.src_path).name,
            # Acción ejecutada sobre ese archivo.
            action,
            # Hora en que se ejecuta la acción.
            datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        ))
```

Tengo mi Clase principal ***`App(tk.Tk)`*** Donde Muestra una ventana 2 Tablas

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.config(width=600, height=500)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title("Registro de modificaciones en tiempo real")

        self.modtree = ttk.Treeview(height = 6, columns=("action", "time",))
        self.modtree.heading("#0", text="Archivo")
        self.modtree.heading("action", text="Acción")
        self.modtree.heading("time", text="Hora")
        self.modtree.grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        Label(self, text = 'TABLA DE SUBCARPETA:').grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
        # create a StringVar class
        my_string_var = StringVar()
        #self.labelEstado = Label(self, text = 'ESTADOS:').grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
        my_string_var.set("What should I learn")
        self.labelEstado = Label(self, textvariable = my_string_var).grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
        

        # TABLA DOS
        self.modTwo = ttk.Treeview(height = 6, columns=("action", "time",))
        self.modTwo.heading("#0", text="Archivo")
        self.modTwo.heading("action", text="Acción")
        self.modTwo.heading("time", text="Hora")
        #modTwo.grid(row = 1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.modTwo.grid(row = 7, column=0, columnspan = 6)

        observer = Observer()
        
        logNombreArch = ''

        q = queue.Queue()
        observer.schedule(CarpPrincial(q), "E:\\MEGA", recursive=False)
        observer.start()

        prueba2 = self.after(1, self.process_events, observer, q, self.modtree, logNombreArch)

    def process_events(self, observer, q, modtree, logNombreArch):
        itemNum = 0
        # Chequear que el observador esté aún corriendo.
        if not observer.is_alive():
            return
        try:
            new_item = q.get_nowait()
            
            itemNum += 1
            # Intentar obtener un evento de la cola.

            if new_item[1] == "Modificado":
                self.my_string_var.set("You must go with Java")

            logNombreArch = new_item[0]
            
        except queue.Empty:
            logNombreArch = '*'
            # Si no hay ninguno, continuar normalmente.
            pass
        else:
            # Si se pudo obtener un evento, agregarlo a la vista de árbol.
            self.modtree.insert("", 0, text=new_item[0], values=new_item[1:])
        
        # Volver a chequear dentro de medio segundo (500 ms).
        self.after(500, self.process_events, observer, q, self.modtree, logNombreArch)

    def process_eventsSubCarpeta(self):
        print("ESTOY EN LA FUNCION DE SUBCARPETA")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo me resalta este Codigo

[image: ERROR OBSERVER]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente reemplaza estas líneas:

```py
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

por estas otras:

```py
    app.observer.stop()
    app.observer.join()
```

Lo que sucedió es que definiste `observer` como un atributo de `App` (y por ende, de su instancia `app`). Así que debes llamarlo como atributo de `app`, y no como una variable independiente.

También, reemplaza las líneas que definan o llamen a `observer` dentro del objeto `App`: cambia `observer` por `self.observer`, así la variable será tratada como un atributo de `App`, y podrás llamarla como `app.observer`.

Comment: Lo puse asi pero no me arroja otro error

Comment: Cambia `observer = ...` por `self.observer = ...`. Eso debe solucionar el problema.

Comment: @FrankStiftYngaYanarico he editado mi respuesta, con más detalles ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si, le agregue app, pero me arroja otro error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trata de no agregar respuestas para responder a una respuesta. Es mejor si usas comentarios ;)

Comment: perdon, soy nuevo en esto jejeje